# average spending per day - django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model that looks something like that:

```
class Payment(TimeStampModel):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(to='Payer')
```

What is the correct way to calculate average spending per day? 
I can aggregate by day, but then the days when a payer does not spend anything won't count, which is not correct

UPDATE:

So, let's say I have only two records in my db, one from March 1, and one from January 1. The average spending per day should be something

```
(Sum of all spendings) / (March 1 - January 1)
```

that is divided by 60

however this of course give me just an average spending per item, and number of days will give me 2:

```
for p in Payment.objects.all():
    print(p.timestamp, p.amount)
p = Payment.objects.all().dates('timestamp','day').aggregate(Sum('amount'), Avg('amount'))
print(p
```

Output:

```
2019-03-05 17:33:06.490560+00:00 456.0
2019-01-05 17:33:06.476395+00:00 123.0
{'amount__sum': 579.0, 'amount__avg': 289.5}
```

Comment: can you add sample data and what you try so far?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman Done - added some info in the update

Comment: What database do you use? My first guess is this is only possible with raw SQL, but then the database type is relevant.

Comment: well you could just calculate the number of day between date min and max sum all the payment on this period and divide your sum of payment by your number of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your backend, but you want to divide the sum of amount by the difference in days between your max and min timestamp. In Postgres, you can simply subtract two dates to get the number of days between them. With MySQL there is a function called DateDiff that takes two dates and returns the number of days between them.

```
class Date(Func):
    function = 'DATE'

class MySQLDateDiff(Func):
    function = 'DATEDIFF'

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        expressions = [Date(exp) for exp in expressions]
        extra['output_field'] = extra.get('output_field', IntegerField())
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)

class PgDateDiff(Func):
    template = "%(expressions)s"
    arg_joiner = ' - '

    def __init__(self, *expressions, **extra):
        expressions = [Date(exp) for exp in expressions]
        extra['output_field'] = extra.get('output_field', IntegerField())
        super().__init__(*expressions, **extra)

agg = {
    avg_spend: ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum('amount') / (PgDateDiff(Max('timestamp'), Min('timestamp')) + Value(1)),
        output_field=DecimalField())
}
avg_spend = Payment.objects.aggregate(**agg)
```

That looks roughly right to me, of course, I haven't tested it. Of course, use MySQLDateDiff if that's your backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate min and max timestamp and the sum of amount:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max, Sum

def average_spending_per_day():
    aggregate = Payment.objects.aggregate(Min('timestamp'), Max('timestamp'), Sum('amount'))
    min_datetime = aggregate.get('timestamp__min')
    if min_datetime is not None:
        min_date = min_datetime.date()
        max_date = aggregate.get('timestamp__max').date()
        total_amount = aggregate.get('amount__sum')
        days = (max_date - min_date).days + 1
        return total_amount / days
    return 0
```

If there is a `min_datetime` then there is some data in the db table, and there is also max date and total amount, otherwise we return 0 or whatever you want.